# Calculate the number of cards with a positive balance for the current date

Tags: sql, hive

I have the next type of table:

```
|client| card| date               | balance|
--------------------------------------------
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 10:04:36|   1000 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 10:07:28|   2980 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 11:23:34|  -100  |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:32:33|  -200  |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:44:43|   100  |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2000 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|  -2100 |
```

In that table we can see one client with two bank cards. Balance is card balance in current moment of time. 
I want to get the count of card with positive balance in that current moment of time.
What i want to see in result

```
|client| card| date               | balance| bal_pos|
-----------------------------------------------------
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 10:04:36|   1000 |   1    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 10:07:28|   2980 |   2    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 11:23:34|  -100  |   1    |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:32:33|  -200  |   0    |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:44:43|   100  |   1    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2000 |   2    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|  -2100 |   1    |
```

How can i calculate count of cards with positive balance?(attribute bal_pos)

P.S I really dont know how to count the number of cards with a positive balance when the date for two cards is the same (last two lines in table).
P.P.S It should work for the next example also:

```
|client| card| date               | balance|
--------------------------------------------
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 10:04:36|   1000 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 10:07:28|   2980 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 11:23:34|   100  |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:32:33|   200  |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:44:43|   100  |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2000 |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2100 |
```

For that case, i expected the next result (because client have only 2 cards in that table,and count of card with positive balance cannot be more than 2):

```
|client| card| date               | balance| bal_pos|
-----------------------------------------------------
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 10:04:36|   1000 |   1    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 10:07:28|   2980 |   2    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 11:23:34|   100  |   2    |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:32:33|   200  |   2    |
|  1   | 123 | 10-01-2018 12:44:43|   100  |   2    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2000 |   2    |
|  1   | 321 | 10-01-2018 14:00:28|   2100 |   2    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below query -

Since even the timestamp can be same, you can define window clause over analytic function (I have taken int col for order by instead of time stamp)

```
with t1 as (select 1 as client, 123 as card, 1 as orderBy, 1000 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 2 as orderBy, 2980 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 3 as orderBy, -100 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 123 as card, 4 as orderBy, -200 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 123 as card, 5 as orderBy, 100 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 6 as orderBy, 2000 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 6 as orderBy, -2100 as bal)
,res1 as (select client, card, orderBy, bal, case when bal>0 then 1 else -1 end as bal_type from t1)
select client, card, orderBy, bal, sum(bal_type) 
over (order by OrderBy asc, bal desc -- this to get output same as yours, but you will never be sure which bal you have to consider if time is same
rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as bal_pos from res1;
```

Results -

```
1       123     1       1000    1
1       321     2       2980    2
1       321     3       -100    1
1       123     4       -200    0
1       123     5       100     1
1       321     6       2000    2
1       321     6       -2100   1
```

If you don't specify window clause instead of calculating sum for each row, it will calculate over range, check the the results for below query.

Query -

```
with t1 as (select 1 as client, 123 as card, 1 as orderBy, 1000 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 2 as orderBy, 2980 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 3 as orderBy, -100 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 123 as card, 4 as orderBy, -200 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 123 as card, 5 as orderBy, 100 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 6 as orderBy, 2000 as bal 
union  
select 1 as client, 321 as card, 6 as orderBy, -2100 as bal)
,res1 as (select client, card, orderBy, bal, case when bal>0 then 1 else -1 end as bal_type from t1)
select client, card, orderBy, bal, sum(bal_type) over (order by OrderBy 
-- range between unbounded preceding and current row -- check the results with range clause
) as bal_pos from res1;

1       123     1       1000    1
1       321     2       2980    2
1       321     3       -100    1
1       123     4       -200    0
1       123     5       100     1
1       321     6       -2100   1 -- sum of first row till current row but based on value of orderBy column (6)
1       321     6       2000    1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah,that works for that example. Thanks a lot.
But what if the balance is always positive and increasing? Your query can return 1,2,3,4 and etc in count of cards if both of cards always have positive balance.
I mean, if in my table i have +100,+200 and +2100 instead of -100,-200,-2100 in balance, your query return 1,2,3,4,5,6,6 in bal_pos (count of cards with positive balance). But that client have only two cards. So, in that example the right result should be 1,2,2,2,2,2,2 
`

Comment: It will still work because for your requirement bal_pos is calculated based on positive or negative balance, not based on values of positive balance.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can upvote if the answer was helpful

Comment: But what if i have another table? And i havent lines with negative balance. All lines in table with positive balance. Your decision will not work correctly. Do you know,how i can adapt your solution to this second example (with only positive balance) ?

Comment: Can you update question with sample data, and expected output